How to customize clang-format for inline multiline lambda after body break before brace
I just updated from llvm 12.0.1 to llvm 18.1.8 and when I run clang-format I am not happy with the modification on inline multiline lambda break before brace :
dispatch(this, [this]
    {
        if (allDataLoaded())
        {
            reload();
        } });

what I had before, that I would like to keep :
dispatch(this, [this]
    {
        if (allDataLoaded())
        {
            reload();
        }
    });

My clang-format configuration is :
Language:        Cpp
BasedOnStyle:  Google
AlignAfterOpenBracket: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakConstructorInitializersBeforeComma: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: false
ColumnLimit:     0
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
IncludeBlocks:   Preserve
IndentWidth:     4
PointerAlignment: Middle
EmptyLineBeforeAccessModifier: Always

I try to add AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None, it fixes the problem but obviously it also affects the single line lambda...
Is there another solution ?
Thanks for your help :)
